# How to solve the error of 'Block invalid'

Tags: parachain, parachain-collator, moonbeam, nimbus

I'm facing this issue after starting parachain: [image]

Note: I have changed the consensus mechanism from **aura to nimbus**(moonbeam use this).

Can anyone please help me to solve this issue ?
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

The relevant part of the error message for you is `supplied author is not eligible`. This means that the nimbus key your node is using is not eligible to author in this slot according to the runtime.

Are you using alicce or some custom keys? Have you inserted them into the node's keystore when starting it? What pallets are you using to select authors and what are their genesis configs?